# How to implement custom post type's users

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I'm still a WordPress rookie and I'm trying to see what is the best approach to handle this. I have a website with about 10,000 users. I also have a Events post type and on each event detail page, users will be able to click "I'm interested in this event" should assign this user to an event. How should I handle this? How should I implement assigning multiple users to a custom post type (there will be an admin section to view Event's users).

Thanks,

Comment: why not just use events-calendar?  it does all this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create for each `Event` a custom post meta (example `event_users`) where you will save the users ID's that clicks the  "I'm interested in this event"

Something like:

`$event_users = get_post_meta($event_id, 'event_users', true); // Get exisitig event users
$event_users[$user_id] = 1; // Add user ID as a KEY, a simple way to make sure you only add it once 
add_post_meta($event_id, 'event_users', $event_users, true) or update_post_meta($event_id, 'event_users', $event_users); // Add/update event users`

Then when you wnat to use this data to get all users for one event is easy just use the `$event_users = get_post_meta($event_id, 'event_users', true);`
Getting all events for a user is a bit more tricky. You can use the WP_Query with meta_query like:

`` [
    `key` => 'event_users',
    `value` => '%:'. $user_id .';%',
    'compare': 'LIKE'
] ``

PS: Array value are serialized on saved, but to be honest I do not like to much serialized values (is just a personal thing), I prefer to convert the values to JSON (json_encode on save, and json_decode when you extract data from DB)

In case you will use json data format meta query will look something like:

`` [
    `key` => 'event_users',
    `value` => '%"'. $user_id .'"%',
    'compare': 'LIKE'
] ``

Check this links for more info:
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

A dedicated plugin for events: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/